# How to build a periodic Java Service using CDI EntityManager

Tags: java, hibernate, cdi

I have a Maven JSF project using Hibernate, Wildfly, CDI is taking care of entity managers' injections, I am using mySql and JTA with datasource setting to access the database.

I need to create a java with a main that periodically access the database and searches for addresses which don't have latitude and longitude. This java will capture new latitudes and longitudes in google maps and then will save these values in a table called RegisteredAddress.

**The problem is that I need to access the RegisteredAddressDAO in this new java file, but EntityManager is injected by CDI. As this java file is going to run alone (wont be fired through request), how can I use this DAO in this java file?**

**standalone-ha.xml - datasource setting**:

```
<datasource jndi-name="java:/dbmap" pool-name="dbmap" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
                <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbmap</connection-url>
                <driver>com.mysql</driver>
                <pool>
                    <min-pool-size>10</min-pool-size>
                    <max-pool-size>100</max-pool-size>
                    <prefill>true</prefill>
                </pool>
                <security>
                    <user-name>root</user-name>
                    <password>a123</password>
                </security>
            </datasource>
```

**Persistence.xml**:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd" version="2.0">

    <persistence-unit name="dbmap" transaction-type="JTA">

        <jta-data-source>java:/dbmap</jta-data-source>


        <class>com.map.model.RegisteredAddress</class>


        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**RegisteredAddress.java**

```
@Entity
public class RegisteredAddress implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer idRegisteredAddress;
    @ManyToOne
    private City city;
    private String zipCode;
    private String address;
    private String neighbourhood;
    private boolean isOfficial;
    private double latitude;
    private double longitude;

    public Integer getIdRegisteredAddress() {
        return idRegisteredAddress;
    }
    public void setIdRegisteredAddress(Integer idRegisteredAddress) {
        this.idRegisteredAddress = idRegisteredAddress;
    }
    public City getCity() {
        return city;
    }
    public void setCity(City city) {
        this.city = city;
    }
    public String getZipCode() {
        return zipCode;
    }
    public void setZipCode(String zipCode) {
        this.zipCode = zipCode;
    }
    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }
    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
    public String getNeighbourhood() {
        return neighbourhood;
    }
    public void setNeighbourhood(String neighbourhood) {
        this.neighbourhood = neighbourhood;
    }
    public boolean isOfficial() {
        return isOfficial;
    }
    public void setOfficial(boolean isOfficial) {
        this.isOfficial = isOfficial;
    }
    public double getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }
    public void setLatitude(double latitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }
    public double getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }
    public void setLongitude(double longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }
}
```

**RegisteredAddressDao**

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Stateless
public class RegisteredAddressDao implements Serializable{
    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em;

    private DAO<RegisteredAddress> dao;

    @PostConstruct
    void init() {
        this.dao = new DAO<RegisteredAddress>(this.em, RegisteredAddress.class);
    }

    public void insert(RegisteredAddress o){
        dao.insert(o);
    }

    public void update(RegisteredAddress o){
        dao.update(o);
    }

    public void remove(RegisteredAddress o){
        this.em.remove(o);
    }

    public RegisteredAddress searchById(Integer ido){
        return dao.searchById(ido);
    }

    public List<RegisteredAddress> listAll(){
        return dao.listAll();
    }
}
```

**DAO**

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class DAO<T> implements Serializable {

    private final Class<T> classe;
    private EntityManager em;

    public DAO(EntityManager manager, Class<T> classe) {
        this.em = manager;
        this.classe = classe;
    }

    public void insert(T t) {
        em.persist(t);
    }

    public void remove(T t) {
        em.remove(em.merge(t));
    }

    public void update(T t) {
        em.merge(t);
    }

    public List<T> listAll() {
        CriteriaQuery<T> query = em.getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery(classe);
        query.select(query.from(classe));

        List<T> list = em.createQuery(query).getResultList();

        return list;
    }

    public T searchById(Integer id) {
        T instance = em.find(classe, id);
        return instance;
    }

    public int countAll() {
        long result = (Long) em.createQuery("select count(n) from livro n")
                .getSingleResult();

        return (int) result;
    }

    public List<T> listAllPaged(int firstResult, int maxResults) {
        CriteriaQuery<T> query = em.getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery(classe);
        query.select(query.from(classe));

        List<T> list = em.createQuery(query).setFirstResult(firstResult)
                .setMaxResults(maxResults).getResultList();

        return list;
    }
}
```

Comment: This sounds like a better use for quartz.  Does it have to be a main?

Comment: Not at all. I am new, is there a good tutorial of quartz that i can have a look?